# Webpack does not resolve less loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less, antd

I'm getting crazy about the configuration of my React-Typescript-Webpack application. It is built from scratch - no `create-react-app` - and should work with the UI library "antd" and "storybook" as well.

After countless hours I now receive following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.less 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
```

... which tells that webpack does not recognize the settings for `less` in `webpack.config.js`, right?

I just don't understand why, because I thought that I added everything necessary ... Can you please help and tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");

const fs = require("fs");

const lessToJs = require("less-vars-to-js");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "none",
  entry: {
    app: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.tsx"),
  },
  target: "web",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".less"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.js$/,
        options: {
          plugins: [["import", { libraryName: "antd", style: true }]],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          {loader: "less-loader"},
        ],
      },
      {
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        test: /\.css$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: "/node_modules/",
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.html"),
    }),
  ],
};
```

And the `babel.rc` file:

```
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
      "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      ["import", 
        {
            "libraryName": "antd",
            "style": true   // or 'css'
          }]
    ]
  }
```

And the dependencies from `package.json`:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.4",
    "antd": "^4.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "less": "2.7.2",
    "less-vars-to-js": "^1.3.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.19",
    "@types/antd": "latest",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.5",
    "@types/webpack": "4.1.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "less-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
}
```

For example, I use antd in `App.tsx` just like this:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import './App.css';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';


const App: FC = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

When I run `npm run build` / `npm start`, everything works fine. The error appears when running `npm run storybook` as stated in the [storybook docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/guides/guide-react/).

Full error stack:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.less 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @import '../../style/themes/index';
| @import '../../style/mixins/index';
| @import './mixin';
 @ ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.js 5:0-23
 @ ./stories/2-Button.stories.js
 @ ./stories sync ^\.\/(?:(?:(?!\.)(?:(?:(?!(?:|[\\/])\.).)*?)[\\/])?(?!\.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.js[\\/]?)$
 @ ./.storybook/generated-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true

ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/lib/style/index.less 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @import './themes/index';
| @import './core/index';
|
 @ ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/style/index.js 3:0-33
 @ ./stories/2-Button.stories.js
 @ ./stories sync ^\.\/(?:(?:(?!\.)(?:(?:(?!(?:|[\\/])\.).)*?)[\\/])?(?!\.)(?=.)[^\\/]*?\.stories\.js[\\/]?)$
 @ ./.storybook/generated-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true
```

Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: The problem is that you are importing a `.less` file from `node_modules`, this is unexpected. files in `node_modules` should be `.js` or `.css`. Anyhow, why not importing like this `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';` as the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd) says?

Comment: Can you add the snippet how you import this package in your code please?

Comment: You can resolve this manually by adding `node_modules` path to webpack `resolve.modules` configuration but I don't think that's how you should resolve this.

Comment: did it worked for you?

Comment: Hello @RazRonen, sorry I was not online the last days. Thing is, I do import just the way you recommend: `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';` Yet the above error appears. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @RazRonen I updated the question showing how I use antd in the component.

Comment: wait, why you have two rules for `.less`? they are overriding each other

Answer (score 0):

Please notice you have two rules for `.less`,
One executes after the other completes.
Try taking one of them off please.

Comment: Oh you're right, I just deleted the second one and tried. But unfortunately the same error :( Updated the `webpack.config` in the question, too. So I updated the `webpack.config` and also deleted `nodeModules` and `package.lock.json`, ran new `npm i`and then ran `npm run storybook` .

Comment: can you try add `node_modules` path in `resolve.modules` webpack configruation please? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules

Comment: and make sure you have `.less` in `resolve.extensions` please

Comment: if it works I'll add it in the answer and explain why

Comment: I did all you recommended, but unfortunately same error :(

Comment: Can you try add a rule like this: ```{
        test: /node_modules\/antd\/lib\/style\/index\.less/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          {loader: "less-loader"},
        ],
      },```    somehow the loaders doesn't catch the node_modules folder

Comment: Still the same error :( I used the code snippet and ran `npm run storybook`. When this didn't work, I removed the style-, css- and less-loader rules from my `webpack.config` and tried again, but still the same output. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: For `test`, I tried to modify your snippet to this (added button): `/\.node_modules\/antd\/lib\/button\/style\/index\.less/` still without success.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here are the steps I did to resolve;

My package.json,

```
"css-loader": "^3.5.3",
"less": "^3.12.2",
"less-loader": "^7.0.0",
"style-loader": "^1.2.0",
"url-loader": "^4.1.0",
"webpack": "^4.43.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
```

My webpack rules config,

```
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    use: [
      "style-loader",
      "css-loader",
      {
        loader: "less-loader",
        options: {
          lessOptions: {
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

Note: Before `less 3.11`, the `javascriptEnabled` is directly inside `options`